# kde, Task Switcher - switch between windows of current application (Kubuntu 20.04)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, task-management

I cannot set the hotkey to switch between windows of the same application to ALT+[key above Tab] on a German keyboard using Task Switcher.

It works when I use a different combination like ALT+1, but for some reason ALT+^ is not accepted.

I am thinking that editing the configuration files directly might be an option, but I do not know where I can find these.

[image: screenshot]

The accepted key combination looks off:

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

This is because ^, ´ and ` are dead keys on the default German keyboard layout. Consider switching to a layout with no dead keys if you want to use these in shortcuts.

Comment: It works perfectly on my other computers with Mint Cinnamon and Ubuntu though. So there must be a way